# Excel VBA: Looping through a combo box's items from another user form

Tags: vba, excel

I want to loop through a combo box's items but not get their values. I just want to loop through how many items there are. Here is how I add items to it.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Chapter.AddItem "Chapter 1"
    Chapter.AddItem "Chapter 2"
    Chapter.AddItem "Chapter 3"
    Chapter.AddItem "No　Chapter"

End Sub
```

And this is what I tried on looping through it.

```
        Dim itm As Object

        For Each itm In UserForm.ComboBox1.Items.Count

        Next
```

But error prompt; Compile error: Method or data member not found

Does it matter that these codes aren't on one user form? I have two user forms and the adding of items to the combo box is on the second and the looping through the combo box is on the first one. Does that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to loop for items count, you can try

```
    Dim itm As Object

    For i = 1 to UserForm1.Chapter.ListCount

    Next
```

Where `Userform1` is the name of the Form that contains Combobox and
`Chapter` is the name of the ComboBox

Answer (score 0):

Try this (without declaration as object):

```
For Each itm In ComboBox1.List
'for example display in messagebox
MsgBox itm 

Next
```

Comment: Error: Object required

Comment: probably UserForm1.Combobox1.List